# r compare column types between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

This may be a bad question because I am not posting any reproducible example. My main goal is to identify columns that are of different types between **two dataframe** that have the **same column names.**

For example

df1

```
 Id      Col1      Col2     Col3
 Numeric Factor    Integer  Date
```

df2

```
 Id      Col1      Col2     Col3
 Numeric Numeric    Integer  Date
```

Here both the dataframes (df1, df2) have same column names but the Col1 type is different and I am interested in identifying such columns. Expected output.

```
Col1  Factor    Numeric
```

Any suggestions or tips on achieving this ?. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
compareColumns <- function(df1, df2) {
  commonNames <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
  data.frame(Column = commonNames,
             df1 = sapply(df1[,commonNames], class),
             df2 = sapply(df2[,commonNames], class)) }
```

Comment: thanks Alex Excellent solution, i added few lines like this, `df3 <- compareColumns(df1,df2)
df3$Diff <- ifelse(df3$df1== df3$df2, "Same", "Different")
df3[df3$Diff =="Different",]`.

Answer (score 6):

Try `compare_df_cols()` from the janitor package:

```
library(janitor)
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$cyl <- as.character(mtcars2$cyl)
compare_df_cols(mtcars, mtcars2, return = "mismatch")

#>   column_name  mtcars   mtcars2
#> 1         cyl numeric character
```

*Self-promotion alert, I authored this package - am posting this function because it exists to solve precisely this problem.*

Answer (score 3):

For a more compact method, you could use a list with `sapply()`.  Efficiency shouldn't be a problem here since all we're doing is grabbing the class.  Here I add data frame names to the list to create a more clear output.

```
m <- sapply(list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2), sapply, class)
m[m[, "df1"] != m[, "df2"], , drop = FALSE]
#      df1      df2        
# Col1 "factor" "character"
```

where `df1` and `df2` are the data from @ycw's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If two data frame have same column names, then below will give you columns with different classes.

```
library(dplyr)
m1 = mtcars
m2 = mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), vs = factor(cyl))
out = cbind(sapply(m1, class), sapply(m2, class))
out[apply(out, 1, function(x) !identical(x[1], x[2])), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` with `class` to loop through all columns in `df1` and `df2`. After that, we can compare the results.

```
# Create example data frames
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,
                  Col1 = as.character(2:4),
                  Col2 = 2:4,
                  Col3 = as.Date(paste0("2017-01-0", 2:4)))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,
                  Col1 = as.character(2:4),
                  Col2 = 2:4,
                  Col3 = as.Date(paste0("2017-01-0", 2:4)),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use sapply and class to find out all the class
class1 <- sapply(df1, class)
class2 <- sapply(df2, class)

# Combine the results, then filter for rows that are different
result <- data.frame(class1, class2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result[!(result$class1 == result$class2), ]
     class1    class2
Col1 factor character
```

Comment: @Sagar Thanks! But I just realized that I made a mistake. `%in%` is not suitable to filter the rows because the comparison is not restricted to the same position. For example, `c("factor", "character", "numeric") %in% c("factor", "numeric", "Date")` results in `TRUE FALSE  TRUE`, but what we need is `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE`. I just replaced `%in%` with `==`, which makes the comparison one to one.

Comment: Good catch. I ran previously and worked fine, but good to bring that up. I am not able to upvote anything. Keeps giving me an error.