# Why are the results of read_csv larger than those of read.csv?

Tags: r, csv, readr

I am importing many (> 300) .csv-files in a project, and I stumbled upon a very strange occurence.

There is a noticable difference in size when comparing the results of `read_csv` and `read.csv`.
Windows lists the file size of all files to be ~442 MB.

Using `readr`

```
library(tidyverse)

datadir <- "Z:\\data\\attachments"
list_of_files <- list.files(path = datadir, full.names = TRUE)

readr_data <- lapply(list_of_files, function(x) {
  read_csv(x, col_types = cols())
})

object.size(readr_data)
#> 416698080 bytes

str(readr_data[1])
#> List of 1
#>  $ : tibble [2,123 x 80] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
```

Using `base` methods

```r
base_data <- lapply(list_of_files, function(x) {
  read.csv(x)
})


object.size(base_data)
#> 393094616 bytes
str(base_data[1])
#> List of 1
#>  $ :'data.frame':    2123 obs. of  80 variables:
```

```
# Compare size
object.size(readr_data) / object.size(base_data) * 100
#> 106 bytes
```

Now 6% may not be that much, but that is still 23 MB, and I am still interested in why these are different. Additionally, both of these are smaller than that reported by Windows.

Why are the lists of different size, and is that important?

EDIT: Apparently some of the classes are different. I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744200/3212698):

```
readr_class <- sapply(readr_data[[1]], class)

base_class <- sapply(base_data[[1]], class)
result <- data.frame(readr_class, base_class)
```

And these are the differences:

```r
                 readr_class base_class
var1              numeric    integer
var2              numeric    integer
var3              numeric    integer
var4              character  integer
```

Comment: One has row numbers and the other does not?

Comment: What are the column classes in each? Posting `str(data)` and `str(data_)` (or comparing them yourself) would lend a lot of insight.

Comment: Some columns might have been read as integer or logical (4 byte only) in one tool but not in the other. Did you check storage mode of fields you read with both tools? Or maybe read_csv keeps some metadata in attributes.

Comment: *"both of these are smaller than that reported by Windows."* Yes - CSV is not an efficient storage type. R data structures have some optimization in place for repeated strings, are aware  classes for the numbers, etc., and should be expected to be at least a little smaller than the CSV representation.

Comment: A minor note: I'd suggest renaming you sample data frames for clarity - `readr_data` and `base_data` would be self-explanatory names.

Comment: @G5W That's a good though, but I think row names would go the other way... `object.size(mtcars)` is 7208 and `object.size(as_tibble(mtcars))` is 4960 - the tibble with simple row names is smaller, but OP is seeing a change in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @GregorThomas. I will also upload the relevant output of `str()` for both cases.

Comment: If your data has many columns, feel free to only post the differences and just note *"the other 200 columns are the same in both versions"* or whatever.

Comment: Are there any quick methods to find the differences in column type, @GregorThomas? I have 80 columns.

Comment: Something like `all.equal(lapply(base_data, class), lapply(readr_data, class))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting the right functions is of course very important for writing efficient code.
The degree of optimization present in different functions and packages will impact how objects are stored, their size, and the speed of operations running on them. Please consider the following.

```
library(data.table)
a <- c(1:1000000)
b <- rnorm(1000000)
mat <- as.matrix(cbind(a, b))
df <- data.frame(a, b)
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(mat)
cat(paste0("Matrix size: ",object.size(mat), "\ndf size: ", object.size(df), " (",round(object.size(df)/object.size(mat),2) ,")\ndt size: ", object.size(dt), " (",round(object.size(dt)/object.size(mat),2),")" ))
Matrix size: 16000568
df size: 12000848 (0.75)
dt size: 4001152 (0.25)
```

So here already you see that `data.table` stores the same data using 4 times less space than your old `matrix` does, and 3 times less than `data.frame`. Now about operations speed:

```
> microbenchmark(df[df$a*df$b>500,], mat[mat[,1]*mat[,2]>500,], dt[a*b>500])
Unit: milliseconds
                             expr       min        lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
          df[df$a * df$b > 500, ] 23.766201 24.136201 26.49715 24.34380 30.243300  32.7245   100
 mat[mat[, 1] * mat[, 2] > 500, ] 13.010000 13.146301 17.18246 13.41555 20.105450 117.9497   100
                  dt[a * b > 500]  8.502102  8.644001 10.90873  8.72690  8.879352 112.7840   100
```

`data.table` does the filtering 1.7 times faster than `base` on `data.frame`, and 2.5 times faster than using a `matrix`.

And that's not all, for almost any CSV import, using `data.table::fread` will change your life. Give it a try instead of `read.csv` or `read_csv`.

IMHO `data.table` doesn't get half the love it deserves, the best all-round package for performance and a very concise syntax. The [following vignettes](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/doc/index.html) should put you on your way quickly, and that is worth the effort, trust me.

For further performance improvements `Rfast` contains many `Rcpp` implementations of popular functions and problems, such as `rowSort()` for example.

---

EDIT: `fread`'s speed is due to optimizations done at C-code level involving the use of pointers for memory mapping, and coerce-as-you-go techniques, which frankly are beyond my knowledge to explain. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424361/reason-behind-speed-of-fread-in-data-table-package-in-r) contains some explanations by the author Matt Dowle, as well as an interesting, if short, piece of discussion between him and the author of `dplyr`, Hadley Wickham.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! Could you comment on why `fread` is better than the alternatives?

Comment: Thanks again. Only issue I had was with large numeric columns, which were interpreted as `integer64`, but that was easily overcome by using `integer64 = "double"`.